# Access Amazon EC2 via Public IP get timeout

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache2

Currently I just create an instance on Amazon EC2 and I can ssh to the server. I installed Apache2 server and it is up but when I try to access via its public ip, then the browser come with timeout error. I have no idea related to EC2 and your idea would be worthwhile for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From EC2 Docs:

If you are unable to see the Apache test page, check that the security group you are using contains a rule to allow HTTP (port 80) traffic. For information about adding an HTTP rule to your security group, see Adding Rules to a Security Group.

Comment: You are right. The default security inbound option is allows only port 22(ssh). To access via web, we should add a new rule called HTTP.

Answer (score 2):

By default all traffics port are blocked for security reason. You need to add Inbound rules for allow http traffic(port 80)
You can add inbound rules by following these steps:
From EC2 Dashboard find "Security Groups" and then "Create Security Group"
[image: Add inbound rules aws ec2]

Give a security group name and description and rules like shown in picture and then create security group.
Now you can access your ec2 public IP from anywhere.

Comment: I initially configured my http inbound as source=anywhere with ::/0 and it was not working and it did not let me modify either. I had to remove that and I added a new one with Custom with 0.0.0.0/0 to make it work.